# Key error in giving weights to nodes in python

Tags: python, tree

I have a graph which has following paths:

```
{45,412,460,462},{45,457}
```

I have to assign weights such that from leaf to root:

1. All the leaf nodes get weight of `A`
2. If a node has one child: Then the weight of the node becomes A*weight of its single child
3. If a node has two or more children then weight of that node is:

   ```
   weight of its child1\*weight of child2\*A\*B
   ```

   For example, the output is final weights of node:

   ```
   462: A, 457: A, 460: A\*A, 412: (A\*A\*A) , 45: A\*B(A\*A\*A\*A)
   ```

I am working with a code in python and I am getting a keyerror 412.

I have three dictionaries:

```
parent_of[node['id']]=parent # parent of a node as value
child_of[node['id']]=children # the list of children of a node
no_child_of[node['id']]=len(child_of[node['id']]) # number of children

#assigning weights to leaf
for c in no_child_of.keys():
    if no_child_of[c]==0:
        weight[c]=A
# assigning weight to the parent
for w in weight.keys():
    par=parent_of[w]
    n=len(child_of[par])
    if n > 1:
        weight[par]=B
        for i in range(n):
            weight[par]=weight[par]*weight[child_of[par][i]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the loop to assign weight to the parent starts with node 457.  `par` then is 45 which has more than one child, so the inner `for` loop tries to get the weight of those children.  `weight` contains the value for the child node 457 but apparently not yet the value for the other child: node 412. Hence the `KeyError`.

I don't see how your approach with that loop assigns weights to other nodes than the direct parents of leaf nodes anyway.

Problems like this are often solved with recursion. Like this for instance:

```
from operator import mul


def assign_weights(parent_of, children_of, a_value, b_value):
    weight_of = dict()

    def calculate_weight(node):
        weight = weight_of.get(node)
        if weight is None:
            children = children_of[node]
            weight = reduce(
                mul,
                (calculate_weight(c) for c in children),
                a_value * (b_value if len(children) > 1 else 1)
            )
        weight_of[node] = weight
        return weight

    for root in (node for node, parent in parent_of.items() if parent is None):
        calculate_weight(root)

    return weight_of


def main():
    # 
    # Data for a tree described by two paths (root to leaf):
    # [45, 412, 460, 462] and [45, 457].
    # 
    parent_of = {45: None, 412: 45, 460: 412, 462: 460, 457: 45}
    children_of = {45: [412, 457], 412: [460], 460: [462], 462: [], 457: []}
    print(assign_weights(parent_of, children_of, 23, 42))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```